# Lockout a user trying to login through the console

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Is there a way I can lockout a user logging in through console (Physical Port) after 3 unsuccessful password attempts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Ubuntu guy, you may want to look into this solution w/ pam_tally2

https://askubuntu.com/questions/338588/limit-user-login-attempts-ubuntu-12-10-pam-tally-so-pam-tally2-so